# Prove that $1 + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{5!} + \frac{4}{7!} + \dotsb = \frac{e}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

> Prove that $1 + \frac{2}{3!} + \frac{3}{5!} + \frac{4}{7!} + \dotsb = \frac{e}{2}$.

This is problem 4 from page 303 of S.L.Loney's 'Plane Trigonometry'.

It seems fairly obvious that the series expansion $e^x$ will be used. However, I am unsure where to start. Should I consider other series?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$e=(1+1)+\left(\frac {1}{2!}+\frac {1}{3!}\right) +\left(\frac {1}{4!}+\frac {1}{5!}\right) +\left(\frac {1}{6!}+\frac {1}{7!}\right) +\cdots=2\left(1+\frac {2}{3!}+\frac {3}{5!}+\frac {4}{7!}+\cdots\right) $$

Q. E. D

Answer (score 23):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{n+1}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(2n+1)+1}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{(2n)!}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\bigg) = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k!} = \frac{e}{2}$$

Maybe the details are not explained well enough. If there is anything unclear just ask.

Comment: Ingenious. I think you ought to have some parentheses around the terms in the penultimate sum, though.

Comment: Well, of course I mean that the sum should be made for both terms (otherwise you would $n$ be?). Anyway, I am editing it.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is 
$$\sinh x=x+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}+\dfrac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$$
then
$$(x\sinh x)'\Big|_{x=1}=2\left(1+\dfrac{2}{3!}+\dfrac{3}{5!}+\dfrac{4}{7!}+\cdots\right)$$
which gives the result.

Comment: +1 very nice. you deserved it.

Answer (score 4):

Your series is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(2n-1)!}.$$
Let $a_n=\frac{n}{(2n-1)!}$, then 
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2n}{(2n-1)!}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2n-1+1}{(2n-1)!}
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(2n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}\right).$$

So $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(2n-1)!}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(2n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{1}{2}e.$$

Comment: You are 4 minutes late ... all the credit goes to @lucamac

Comment: Yes, it does not matter!